# realloc(): invalid next size and double free

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

As a homework, I'm supposed to create 2 functions that enable you to push and pop elements to an array that acts as a queue. We're supposed to do this dynamically allocating memory. My program is almost working, but sometimes when adding and removing too many elements, I get errors like "realloc(): invalid next size", double free (when I've only called the free function once) and some of the elements in the beginning of the queue are set to 0. For instance, if I first add 100 elements, then remove 90 and try to add another 20, I get "free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001ea6010".
What am I doing wrong here?

According to suggestions below I changed my functions to take a double pointer as an input for the array. That, however, now gives me a Segmentation fault - which means now I don't know what to look for at all...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void enqueue(int **arr, int* lastElementIdx, size_t* totalElements, int element) {
    if (*lastElementIdx >= *totalElements) {        // check if memorry is sufficient, otherwise double
        *totalElements *= 2;

        int* temp = realloc(arr, (*totalElements * sizeof(int)));

        if (temp == NULL) {         // just in case realloc fails
            printf("Allocation error\n");
        } else {
            *arr = temp;
        }
    }

    if (*lastElementIdx <= *totalElements) {
        *lastElementIdx += 1;       // once everything is done: add element
        *arr[*lastElementIdx] = element;
    }
}

int dequeue(int **arr, int* lastElementIdx, size_t* totalElements) {
    if (*lastElementIdx > -1) {     // if queue is not empty...
        int deleted = *arr[0];      // save deleted value first (in case it's still needed)
        for (int i = 0; i <= *lastElementIdx; i++) {    // shift all elements
            *arr[i] = *arr[i + 1];
        }
        *lastElementIdx -= 1;   // index is now decreased by 1

        if (((*totalElements / 2) >= 10) && ((*lastElementIdx + 1) < (*totalElements / 2))) {   // cut memory in half if not needed
            *totalElements /= 2;

            *arr = realloc(arr, (*totalElements * sizeof(int)));
            int* temp = realloc(arr, (*totalElements * sizeof(int)));
            if (temp == NULL) {     // in case realloc fails
                printf("Allocation error\n");
                return 0;
            } else {
                *arr = temp;
            }
        }

        return deleted;
    } else {        // if queue is empty, print that there's nothing to dequeue
        printf("There are no elements inside the queue\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void printQueue(int arr[], int lastElementIdx) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastElementIdx; i++) {     // print entire queue
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main (void) {

    size_t totalElements = 10;      // number of needed elements at the time
    int lastElementIdx = -1;        // index of last element in queue at the time
    int *arr = calloc(totalElements, sizeof(int));
    int **arrpointer = &arr;

    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        enqueue(arrpointer, &lastElementIdx, &totalElements, i);
    }

    printQueue(arr, lastElementIdx);

    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        dequeue(arrpointer, &lastElementIdx, &totalElements);
    }

    printQueue(arr, lastElementIdx);

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        enqueue(arrpointer, &lastElementIdx, &totalElements, i);
    }

    printQueue(arr, lastElementIdx);

    free(arr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Error handling is more than just printing a message, but otherwise ignoring the fault.

Comment: BTW Do not compare the variables  of size_t and `-1` .

Comment: Run your program in a debugger, and you'll see what your program was trying to do that caused the segfault.

Comment: `int* temp = realloc(arr,`  --> `int* temp = realloc(*arr,`,  `*arr[*lastElementIdx] = element;` --> `(*arr)[*lastElementIdx] = element;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you. that did get rid of the seg fault at least... but it's still no good, i'm still getting realloc(): invalid next size...

Comment: @mimtschan remember my first comment. "Do not compare the variables of size_t and -1"

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oh, yes... I didn't ignore that, I tried to fix this by typecasting to (int)(*totalElements), but that doesn't give the desired results... am I doing it wrong? (I'm sorry, I hope I'm not totally butchering pointers, as you can probably see I don't have a full grasp on the concept yet :/)

Comment: sorry, already implemented. Last index can not be compared directly as the total size in order to start from -1. E.g change to `if (*lastElementIdx + 1 >= (int)*totalElements) {`, `if (*lastElementIdx +1 < (int)*totalElements) {`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh my god. Yes, that fixed it! It's finally working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the only problem, but at least the following line does not what you seem to expect:

`*temp = *arr;`

It looks as if you want to replace arr with the result of the realloc, delivering it back to the calling function (as with your other inout arguments).  But, arr is not an inout argument: It is an array of integers, not a pointer to an array of integers.  What you are actually doing with your above line of code is to copy the first element of arr to the newly allocated memory range.  That newly allocated memory range temp, then, is nevertheless forgotten, creating a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

When you expand or contract the storage for your queue, you need to provide a pointer to the storage back to the caller.  This is because `realloc()` does not necessarily resize a memory block in-place -- it may create a new, differently sized block elsewhere.  It is permitted to do so even when it resizes to a smaller block, not only when it resizes to a larger one.

Your usage of variable `temp` gives the appearance that you are aware of this issue, but as @DerkHermann first observed, you mishandle the resulting pointer.  Perhaps you meant to write something along the lines of

```
arr = temp;
```

instead.  Even that is not sufficient, however.  C has only pass-by-value, so if you modify the value of function parameter `arr`, that modification is visible only in the function (which receives in `arr` a *copy* of the value the caller passes).  In the event that `realloc()` allocates a new block, that leaves the caller with an invalid pointer.

If you want your `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` functions to be able to resize the storage for the queue, then you must pass the pointer to that storage *indirectly*.  The most straightforward way of doing that, given where you are now, would be to pass a double pointer, so that you can modify its referrent:

```
void enqueue(int **arr, int* lastElementIdx, size_t* totalElements, int element) {
    /* ... */
    *arr = temp;
    /* ... */
}
```

Observe, however, that you are passing three separate pointers that among them represent the state of the queue.  It would be cleaner to create a `struct` type that combines those details in one package, and to pass a pointer to an object of that type:

```
struct queue {
    int *arr;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t last_element_index;
};

void enqueue(struct queue *queue, int element) {
    /* ... */
    queue->arr = temp;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your detailed answer! I didn't realize that the block wouldn't be carried outside the function. (I hurriedly added the temp variable because I was aware I should catch those errors - I realize it shows that I didn't check it thoroughly...) I did add a double pointer, however I am now getting a segmentation fault...

Comment: @mimtschan, your revised code has a problem with operator precedence.  The array indexing operator (`[]`) has higher precedence that the dereferencing operator (unary `*`), so expressions such as `*arr[*lastElementIdx]` don't mean what you intend.  You want `(*arr)[*lastElementIdx]` instead.

Comment: @mimtschan, Additionally, you missed the needed change from `arr` to `*arr` in your `realloc()` calls.

Comment: thank you! BLUEPIXY made the same suggestions above and I already changed it earlier today, which did get rid of the segmentation fault. but it seems the entire double pointer thing didn't fix anything, now I don't even get anything to print/be added to the queue before i get the realloc(): invalid next size... at this point I honestly don't know what to do with this... :/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a double pointer to reallocate the space in the right places, changing the comparing function with size_t totalElements and fixing a few additional mistakes finally did the trick.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void enqueue(int **arr, int* lastElementIdx, size_t* totalElements, int element) {
    if (*lastElementIdx + 1 >= (int)(*totalElements) - 1) {     // check if memorry is sufficient, otherwise double
        *totalElements *= 2;

        int* temp = realloc(*arr, (*totalElements * sizeof(int)));
        if (temp == NULL) {         // just in case realloc fails
            printf("Allocation error\n");
        } else {
            *arr = temp;
        }
    }

    if (*lastElementIdx + 1 <= (int)(*totalElements) - 1) {
        *lastElementIdx += 1;       // once everything is done and if there is now enough space: add element
        (*arr)[*lastElementIdx] = element;
    }
}

int dequeue(int **arr, int* lastElementIdx, size_t* totalElements) {
    if (*lastElementIdx > -1) {     // if queue is not empty...
        int deleted = (*arr)[0];        // save deleted value first (in case it's still needed)
        for (int i = 0; i <= *lastElementIdx; i++) {    // shift all elements
            (*arr)[i] = (*arr)[i + 1];
        }
        *lastElementIdx -= 1;   // index is now decreased by 1

        if (((*totalElements / 2) >= 10) && ((*lastElementIdx + 1) < (*totalElements / 2))) {   // cut memory in half if not needed
            *totalElements /= 2;

            int* temp = realloc(*arr, (*totalElements * sizeof(int)));
            if (temp == NULL) {     // in case realloc fails
                printf("Allocation error\n");
                return 0;
            } else {
                *arr = temp;
            }
        }

        return deleted;
    } else {        // if queue is empty, print that there's nothing to dequeue
        printf("There are no elements inside the queue\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void printQueue(int arr[], int lastElementIdx) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastElementIdx; i++) {     // print entire queue
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main (void) {

    size_t totalElements = 10;      // number of needed elements at the time
    int lastElementIdx = -1;        // index of last element in queue at the time
    int *arr = calloc(totalElements, sizeof(int));
    int **arrpointer = &arr;

    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        enqueue(arrpointer, &lastElementIdx, &totalElements, i);
    }

    printQueue(arr, lastElementIdx);

    for (int i = 0; i < 102; i++) {
        dequeue(arrpointer, &lastElementIdx, &totalElements);
    }

    printQueue(arr, lastElementIdx);

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        enqueue(arrpointer, &lastElementIdx, &totalElements, i);
    }

    printQueue(arr, lastElementIdx);

    free(arr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: I think `(int)(*totalElements) - 1`: `-1` Is not required. because last index + 1 is number of (used)elements.